# What is the quickest method to see actual color of any hex code #a7a7a7?

Tags: css, xhtml

What is the quickest method to see the actual color of the hex code #a7a7a7?

When i work on another's CSS, I want to be able to quickly see the color of that particular hex code.

Example: If I'm editing CSS in notepad, and I found code #a7a7a7, then how can I know what color this code corresponds to?

I already have tools that can give me a hex value for a color on screen, but I need one that does the opposite.

I don't want a color chart; I just want a tool to convert from hex value to color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You drop notepad as an editor and choose from one of the many freely available CSS editors?

Random example:
http://speckyboy.com/2008/09/15/7-free-css-editors-which-is-the-best-you-choose/

---

**EDIT**: So... to make this a programming question, and since you are on Windows XP, I made a little [HTA application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496(VS.85).aspx) that does color code previews:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:hta="http://tempuri.org/microsoft/hta">
<head>
  <title>Hex Helper</title>
  <hta:application 
    id="HexColor"
    version="0.1"
    applicationname="Hex Helper"
    sysmenu="yes"
    maximizebutton="no"
    minimizebutton="no"
    border="dialog"
    innerborder="no"
    scroll="no"
    selection="no"
    contextmenu="no"
    windowstate="normal"
  />
  <style type="text/css"> 
    * {
      border: 0 none; margin: 0; padding: 0; 
    }
    html, body { 
      height:100%;
      background-color: black; 
    }
    #container {
      padding: 5px; 
    }
    #preview {
      width: 130px; height: 90px; 
      border: 2px ridge;
    }
    #colorcode {
      width: 100%;
      height: 1.2em;
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var trim      = /^\s+|\s$/g;
    var fullColor = /^\s*#?([a-f0-9]{6})\s*$/;
    var abbrColor = /^\s*#?([a-f0-9])([a-f0-9])([a-f0-9])\s*$/;

    function setColor(hex) {
      hex = hex.replace(trim, "");

      var preview = document.getElementById("preview");
      var m = null;

      if (m = fullColor.exec(hex)) {
        preview.style.backgroundColor = "#"+m[1];
      } else if (m = abbrColor.exec(hex)) {
        preview.style.backgroundColor = "#"+m[1]+m[1]+m[2]+m[2]+m[3]+m[3];
      }
    }

    function setValue(preview) {
      var colorcode = document.getElementById("colorcode")
      colorcode.value=preview.style.backgroundColor;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="window.resizeTo(150,150)">
  <form action="#" id="container">
    <div id="preview" onclick="setValue(this);"></div>
    <input id="colorcode" type="text" maxlength="7" onkeyup="setColor(this.value);" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Save the above to a file called `HexHelper.hta` and run the file. Here is how it looks like. Feel free to modify in any way you want.

[Hex Helper screen stot http://img203.imageshack.us/img203/8122/hexhelper.png](http://img203.imageshack.us/img203/8122/hexhelper.png)

Comment: this is not a point of my question , ok tell me how to see color of code in dreamweaver?

Comment: suppose I opened a css file in dreamweaver code view and i have a code ##a7a7a7 , now how to see the color of this code.

Comment: @metal: Easy - you drop Dreamweaver as a CSS editor and... Seriously, why do you want to edit CSS in the wrong tools? I suppose there is a small program that does what you want, though. Tried searching the Windows Gadget gallery already?

Comment: i need a tool like where i can paste the code and see the color

Comment: @metal: Hm, Ive found this one: http://gallery.live.com/liveItemDetail.aspx?li=a09a227e-a6ab-41eb-8123-935f7849011f&bt=1

Comment: thanks looking but i'm on Windows XP so i can't use this tool.

Comment: @Tomalak which free CSS editor has facility like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703462/what-is-the-quikest-method-to-see-actual-color-of-any-hex-code-a7a7a7/2703548#2703548 ?

Comment: @metal: Oh, I didn't mention. Save it to a file called `HexHelper.hta` and run that file.

Answer (score 2):

After searching a lot i found a good online tool to do this

http://chir.ag/projects/name-that-color/

Here we can paste code and see the color.

[alt text http://shup.com/Shup/322305/11032475925-My-Desktop.png](http://shup.com/Shup/322305/11032475925-My-Desktop.png)

Comment: awesome!! Chirag is also having some other little cool projects

Answer (score 2):

1. Open [ColorZilla](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/271) firefox addon
2. type color code
3. press enter.

Answer (score 1):

You might find this tool useful:

http://hexpreview.com/

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop? I don't see how this is really a question for the SO community but I work a lot with photoshop and typically have photoshop running in the background. That way I can easily switch to photoshop and use the color tool to look a different hex values. There's also plenty of tools on the web for this. On which I'm particulary fond of is the [Color Scheme Designer 3](http://colorschemedesigner.com/). Just click the hex value and enter your color hex value and it will show you what color it is.

Eventually you wouldn't need these tools, you should be able to learn what codes map to what color space. And just go with the feeling of what a particular hex color value might look like.

Comment: you are not getting my question.. "If i have a color on my screen then i quickly know what would be hex code for this with the help of some tools ,but i need just opposite of this."

Comment: @metal - He understands your question perfectly. Photoshop's color picker allows you to input a hex value and see the color it represents.

Comment: @Jimmy - but that i already know and I asked for quick solution

Comment: Then I don't see the point of this question at all? You can easily use print screen and the color picker inside photoshop to grab a color from any screen on your computer and you can easily use the color dialog to find a new color. If that's not what you want then your asking for something very unfamiliar and strange.

Answer (score 0):

This might sound crazy, but yeah this is very easy and handy to do.
write a plain html.

```
<html>
  <body bgcolor="#a7a7a7"></body>
</html>
```

now, open this page on your  browser. Keep on changing  bgcolor to whatever color you want to see and refreshing the browser :)

another option is, create any html and include the css you are trying to edit. Open that page on firefox, now using firebug you can see the color. { Just hover over the css color code and you will see the color ]

[alt text http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/764/62889051.jpg](http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/764/62889051.jpg)

Comment: this is very long . i was not asking for this. just to see color i don't want to create HTML page and go to firefox ,firegbug.

Answer (score 0):

This tool is pretty useful and is free:

http://www.iconico.com/colorpic/